# xte and keyboard mapping

Tags: xorg, xinput, xte

I'm trying to fake `xinput` events with `xte`:

```
xte "str $(echo '<ABC@gmail.com>')"
```

But, I get:

```
WQBC@g;qil<co;X
```

That's really weird, I'm using US keyboard and mapping, but `xte` gives this very different result.

**UPDATE**

Output from `xte "str '<ABC@gmail.com>'"`

`4WQBC@g;qil<co;X4`

Comment: Does `xte "str '<ABC@gmail.com>'"` work?  (This is probably not what you want (in the end), but for debugging...)

Comment: @sr_ rather wired

Comment: @sr_ , i configured both french and english keyboard in xorg.conf , but since my current output has no problems , it shouldn't happen with xtr either

Comment: Hmm. Both outputs differ in the quotation marks only (`'`=`4`, apparently)...

Comment: [This discussion is enlightening](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=415451) (not sure if the patch helps, though)  [but apparently upstream fixed that issue](http://www.hoopajoo.net/projects/xautomation.html)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you can try:

```
xdotool type  --clearmodifiers -delay 0 "string to type at fake input"
```

I found it works a lot better than xte version 1.02 which seemed to have a 255 character limit.  Or xte version 1.0.7 which seemed to ignore all newlines in the string.